# fill model's fields before post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i pass a model to my view . and it's fields are hiddenfor.
and my tds are here(in this view)

how can i say when i click on button(submit-btn2) , first  my java script codes execute . and then my filled model will be post ?

my Partialview :

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.username)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Tell)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Mobil)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Lname)

      <button class="btn btn-medium btn-general input-block-level" id="submit-btn2"   type="submit">save</button>

          //all tds are here in this page(this view)

        // $(document).ready(function () {
        //$('#submit-btn2').click(function () {
        //$("#username").val($(".tdBuyername").val());
        //$("#Tell ").val($(".tdPhone").val());
        //$("#Name ").val($(".tdRecievername").val());
        //$("#Mobil ").val($(".tdMobile").val());
        //$("#Lname ").val($(".tdLname").val());
          //});
        // });



      <script type="text/javascript">

$("#submit-btn2").click(function () { saveMyModel();});

function SaveMyModel()
{
    var e = document.getElementById("id_purchase");
    var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    var e2 = document.getElementById("id_spend");
    var str2 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Save", "Home")',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            jsonMyModel: {

                username: $(".tdBuyername").val(),
                Tell: $(".tdPhone").val(),
                Name: $(".tdRecievername").val(),
                Mobil: $(".tdMobile").val(),
                Lname: $(".tdLname").val(),

                id_purchase: $("# id_purchase ").val(str),
                id_spend: $("# id_spend ").val(str2),
            }

            })
    });
}
```

Mycontroller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Customer()
    {
        var obj = new Project.Models.ModelClasses.ViewModelX();
        return PartialView(obj);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Save(ViewModelX jsonMyModel)
    {
        var result = true;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

          result= MyClass.Insert (jsonMyModel.Address, jsonMyModel.Cod,
                jsonMyModel.idpurchase,
                jsonMyModel.idspend, jsonMyModel.Lname,
                jsonMyModel.Name, jsonMyModel.Tell, jsonMyModel.username);

        }
        else
        {

        }

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

MyClass:

```
    public class ViewModelX
    {
    public Nullable< long > idpurchase { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> idspend { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Lname { get; set; }
    public string Tell { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string CodPosti { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following to the end of your `click` handler:

```
$('#myForm').submit();
```

Where `myForm` is the id attribute of your form.

Assuming your controller action accepts a parameter matching the class that your view is typed to, the model binder should take care of it as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a strongly typed model?

What you have described can be done in two ways.

1. Using `AJAX` to post your data without page reload.
2. Using normal form post to post data.

## Using AJAX

Having assumed that your controller method is like:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Save(MyModel jsonMyModel)
{
 //do saving stuff
}
```

where , your model `MyModel` looks like

```
public class MyModel()
{
  public string Username { get; set;}
  public string Tell { get; set;}
  public string Name { get; set;}
  public string Mobile { get; set;}
  public string LastName { get; set;}
}
```

You can create the model that your controller method accepts using normal jquery or javascript and post it using AJAX as below:

```
 $("#submit-btn2").click(function () { saveMyModel();});

 function SaveMyModel()
 {
        $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Method", "SomeController")',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    jsonMyModel: {
                        Username:  $("#username").val(),
                        Tell: $("#Tell ").val(),
                        Name: $('#listviewlabel').val(),
                        Mobile: $("#Name ").val(),
                        LastName:$("#Lname ").val() 
                    })
           });
 }
```

## Using normal form post

You can directly google out this thing. You can even find this in your account controller.

Comment: Bhushan Firake thanks . i updated my code. i'm updating my question.can you tell me it's true?

Comment: is it possible [httpGet] be ActionResult and [HttpPost] be JsonResult?